# Kernel Restarting with MICE imputation

Tags: python, imputation, miceforest

When I run this, my kernel immediately restarts with no explanation. It restarts even when my df only has dimensions 10x5. Does anyone know why?

```
import miceforest as mf

kds = mf.ImputationKernel(
    X_test_missing,
    save_all_iterations=True,
    random_state=100
)
kds.mice(5)
```